# Getting @LinkingObjects backlink in unmanaged RealmObject?

Tags: android, realm

with the new 3.4.0 realm version we are able to get automatick backlinks via @LinkingObject, works, however, is there a way I can get these backlinks in unmanaged state? Backlinking realm results are aways null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you need to define backlinks as

```
@LinkingObjects("linkingObjectsField")
private final RealmResults<OtherObject> backlink = null;
```

And `realm.copyFromRealm()` ignores backlinks, unmanaged objects can't have the backlink field set. Generally, you wouldn't need to access backlinks in a detached object.

So a possible workaround would be

```
@LinkingObjects("linkingObjectsField")
private final RealmResults<OtherObject> backlink = null;

@Ignore
private List<OtherObject> unmanagedBacklink = Collections.emptyList();

public <T extends List<OtherObject>> T getBacklinkObjects() {
    if(isManaged()) {
        // noinspection unchecked
        return (T)backlink; // <-- so that this can be obtained as RealmResults<T>
    } else {
        // noinspection unchecked
        return (T)unmanagedBacklink;
    }
}
```

And you can manually copy the backlinks with `realm.copyFromRealm(obj.getBacklink());` on a managed instance of `obj`.

---

Or just use a managed object, considering I do not see the use-case where you need unmanaged backlinks (other than maybe sending them through GSON, but even then I generally recommend having explicit DTO classes instead).